# Three methods to search: name; name and surname; and age in an array

Tags: java

I have a class called "`Person`", where the attributes are: name, surname and age. I have already created it, it is simple, it is composed only of setters and getters. But then I have another class called "`PersonDatabase`", which is a bit more complicated for me. I will show it here:

```
public class PersonDatabase {

    private Person[] persons;
    private int personCount;

    public PersonDatabase(int defaultPersonsCapacity) {
        persons = new Person[defaultPersonsCapacity];
        personCount = 0;
    }

    public void addPerson(String name, String surname, int age) {

        if (personCount == persons.length) {
            System.out.println("Unable to add Person.");
            return;
        }

        persons[personCount] = new Person(name, surname, age);
        personCount++;

        System.out.println("Person added.");
    }

    public int getPersonCount() {
        return personCount;
    }
```

This is what I have of it till now, but I have to create another three methods in it, one to get only the name, another to get the name and surname and another to get only age of a person.

I know how to basically "begin" them. The first would be:

```
public Person searchPerson (String name) {

}
```

The second and the third should be alike. They should have the same "data type" (the class Person) and name "`searchPerson`", changing only what they should return, the second should return the name and the surname of the person, and the third should return the age of the person.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: ldap search have a similar interface, where you specify the search criteria:  **uid=foo** , or **email=foo@...**

Comment: Why do you use an array (`Person[]`) instead of an `ArrayList<Person>`? You would get rid of the `personCount` if you did...

Comment: It is just that it is an exercise, and it says that it should be remains like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just iteration for persons and check `getName()`. But for education propose, you always need to check that person name can be `null`, or searchPerson function will called with `null` parameters (NullPointerException is very bad mistake for java developer and you teacher can check you api).

```
public Person searchPerson (String name) {
    for (Person person: persons) {
        if (name != null && name.equals( person.getName())) {
          return person;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("We can not found Person with name " + name);
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Viacheslav Vedenin. But I still have some problems with it. For example, when I tried to create the method for the age, the "if" part of the code is not accepting the "equals(age)". Should I replace it somehow? I have just searched it, and I have not found any answer for it. Another thing, when I created the second method to return the name and the surname, I used two "if"'s, should it be like that? Unhappilly, I do not know how to represent it here in the comments, so I am sorry for that.  Thank you again.

Comment: For int you should use only ==, for example if (p.getAge() == age)

Answer (score 1):

The idea would be to iterate over your array and compare the parameter `name` something like

```
public Person searchPerson(String name) {
    for (Person p: persons) {
        if (p.getName().equals(name)) return p;
    }
    return null; // person could not be found
}
```